# ASP / PHP shared encryption

Tags: php, asp.net, encryption, authentication

Need a bit of advice here! I'm currently working on a project in which agencies and clients can both login to a 'dashboard'. However all the client dashboard is created in PHP, and the Agency stuff in ASP.Net (don't even ask!). However I need the functionality for an agency to do the following:

- Agency logs in.
- Agency clicks view client link
- Agency is logged into client UI automatically and views client page.

Obviously this is difficult as trying to auth between ASP.NET and PHP! However I have come up with the following solution - will this work?

- Agency clicks view client.
- ASP.NET encrypts, using a key, a few bits of important info as well as a timestamp.
- ASP POSTs this request to a PHP page
- PHP decrypts using the key, checks that the user exists in DB and checks that this agency has permission to view the requested client page. Also checks timestamp is within say 10 seconds.
- IF all above is OK, then agency is logged into to PHP and sees client page.

What are your thoughts?

And what would be the best encryption method for both ASP/PHP?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Is it the same cookie domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is build out a Single Sign On ([SSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)) platform. Create your own Identity provider and than migrate both applications to authenticate against it.

[Here is a Zend Webinar with some information to get you started.](http://www.slideshare.net/ijansch/building-an-sso-platform-in-php-zend-webinar-edition)

Comment: +1 for SSO, this would let you have the applications just authenticate the SSO independently without worry.

Comment: We already have some kind of SSO in the form of Janrain Engage, but I can't see how this would pass auth between the two languages securely?

Comment: You don't need to pass the auth between the two languages, you authenticate with the SSO.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow! (New to all this SSO stuff!). So, say the user logged into the agency page and clicked the client link, how would the client page know they were logged in?

Comment: Say everything uses facebook for SSO. User logs into the agency page, which authenticates him against and logs him into facebook. If he goes to the client page, the page sees he is logged into facebook and does not request he logs in. If the user logs out of facebook, they will not be able to log into either the client or user page. In a sense it is piggybacking authentication off of facebook cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I would do all of this communication over [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), as it's very hard to write this yourself correctly. If you send all the data through TLS, you shouldn't have to worry about doing any encryption yourself. You can just use the basic scheme you described, but using TLS for the encrypted data channel.